# SSRS VB IIF statement returning error for NULL value

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, null

Im wondering if some can help we understand why SSRS returns Error in the my Textbox13 text box.

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox13.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from string "NULL" to type 'Date' is not valid.

The value Workorder_Closed_Date is a result of a sql query, and is either filled in or NULL

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Workorder_Closed_Date.Value),
    reportitems!Textbox13.Value="open",
    reportitems!Textbox13.Value="closed")
```

Comment: Is that expression for `Textbox13`?

Answer (score 3):

If that expression is for `Textbox13`, then this would work:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!WorkOrder_Closed_Date.Value), "open", "closed")
```

Note that `IIf` executes both *true* and *false* parts, so you want a *constant expression* in each branch of the condition, not side-effects.

> ```
> =IIf(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
> ```

---

Oh god.

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox13.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: **Conversion from string "NULL" to type 'Date' is not valid**

Your value isn't `null` (or `Nothing` actually) - it's a STRING literal that contains the VALUE `"NULL"`.

You need to fix your data, not your report.

Comment: Tried this,  but it looks like SSRS is rejecting    Fields!WorkOrder_Closed_Date.Value

Comment: I did not notice this before but I am getting the following error    Warning 1 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox13.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from string "NULL" to type 'Date' is not valid.

Comment: Odd, the Database field is datatime, that would mean SSRS is changing the field type...

Comment: I think I understand your saying that the database is changing it to a string with the text value of NULL, If thats the case, Im surprised because the database is from a reputable Vendor

Comment: Your data source (view, stored procedure, inline SQL) is probably doing conversions "for convenience". If the database is storing dates as dates, there's hope.

Comment: The Data source is a table, and the datatype is DATATIME. if that were true  would this work    =IIF(CStr(Fields!Workorder_Closed_Date.Value) = "NULL","open","closed")

Comment: Oddly enough it does work, I still get the error though